# webdriverio element undefined inside arrow function

Tags: javascript, node.js, selenium-webdriver, webdriver-io

I am working on webdriverio automation project. I have the following code.

```
waitUntilVisible(element, maxTimeOut) {
    console.log("********** PARAMETER ************" + element);

    const testelement = $('#identifierId');

    browser.waitUntil(testelement => {

        console.log("************** INSIDE *********" + testelement);

        return testelement.isDisplayed();

    }, maxTimeOut, 'Wait for element to be visible');
}
```

testelement is always returning undefined. Could some one suggest me what is going wrong.

Comment: You are shadowing the `testelement` within the `browser.waitUntil` which you have already defined on the line above. What happens if you do `const testelement = $('#identifierId'); browser.waitUntil(() => { // rest of the stuff }`?

Comment: @norbertpy The code I provided above is just a reference. element is different from testelement. Is that what you are referring to?

Comment: `testelement` is defined twice. If that makes more sense to you.

Comment: @norbertpy I get it now. So can you suggest me how I can pass testelement to waitUntil method arrow function?

Comment: https://webdriver.io/docs/api/browser/waitUntil.html

Comment: For the record what I said in my first comment probably works.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Why don't use [waitForDisplayed](https://webdriver.io/docs/api/element/waitForDisplayed.html)?

But if you want to use your own - you have problem with calling your function

```js
waitUntilVisible(element, maxTimeOut) {
    console.log("********** PARAMETER ************" + element);
    //this is never called due same name of variable in fn waitUntil
    const testelement = $('#identifierId');
```

**Possible fixes:**

```js
// if you want to pass selector 
waitUntilVisible(elementSelector, maxTimeOut) {
    console.log("********** PARAMETER ************" + elementSelector);
    browser.waitUntil(testelement => {
        console.log("************** INSIDE *********" + elementSelector);
        return $(elementSelector).isDisplayed();
    }, maxTimeOut, 'Wait for element to be visible');
}

// if you want to pass WebDriverIO object 
waitUntilVisible(element, maxTimeOut) {
    console.log("********** PARAMETER ************");
    browser.waitUntil( () => {
        console.log("************** INSIDE *********");
        return element.isDisplayed();
    }, maxTimeOut, 'Wait for element to be visible');
}
```

Answer (score 1):

```
/**
 * Check if the given element is (not) visible
 * @param  {String}   selector   Element selector
 * @param  {String}   falseCase Check for a visible or a hidden element
 */
const isDisplayed = async (selector, falseCase) => {
    let elem = await browser.$(selector);
    const displayed = await elem.isDisplayed();
    if (falseCase) {
        expect(displayed).to.not
            .equal(true, `Expected element "${selector}" not to be displayed`);
    } else {
        expect(displayed).to
            .equal(true, `Expected element "${selector}" to be displayed`);
    }
}
```

use browser.$(selector) and use that element to continue with your test. I have added a method to check if element is isDisplayed.